# How to extract text from within a cell using macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have the following text in a cell that i want to concatenate to another cell.

Pre-Condition:
1. ABC
2. ABC
3. ABC
4. ABC

PQRSTUV

I want to extract the following text:

Pre-Condition:
1. ABC
2. ABC
3. ABC
4. ABC

I tried using a macro by seaching two newline characters, but it is not working. Please suggest i have loads of data that I need to perform this task.

Comment: It could be due to the formatting or the way your question is phrased, but I don't know what it is you want. Please show the data you have and how the data should look afterwards. If you want to format text in mono-space, just add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is more information on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following formula
=LEFT(A1;FIND("
";A1))

assuming A1 the cell containing your data

for the first parameter of FIND function type ALT-ENTER on the keyboard, enclosed by "

regards
michel

Answer (score 0):

The formula will look like this in Excel :

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND("

";A1))
```